# Filtering on two values in column using XML

Tags: xml, filtering, dynamic-list

I have an issue with an entry form I am trying to filter values on.  It is using XML and pulling information from a SQL database in the following format:

| PLX_UOM_ID | UNIT_OF_MEASURE | UOM_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | FT | DISTANCE |
| 1001 | C | TEMPERATURE |
| 1002 | KPA | ALL |
| 1003 | PSI | ALL |
| 1004 | CM/SEC | DISTANCE |
| 1005 | TR/IN | ALL |

The end result is that I'd like to pull back information using the entry form for records which are filtered on two of the values in 'UOM_TYPE', namely 'DISTANCE' and 'ALL'.  I am able to filter on one value, however I can't get things working with two.

The XML for the entry form I need to update is here:

```
    <SelectOne id="tb21" label="Horizontal Scale Uom" field="PlxRUnitOfMeasure" isPartOfHierarchicalFlow="false" selectSingle="false" showAsCombo="false">
      <parent class="PanelGrid" reference="../.."/>
      <listenerEvents/>
      <validators/>
      <dataList class="DynamicList" table="PlxRUnitOfMeasure" valueField="" separator=" | " filterField="uomType" filterValue="">
        <selectList class="SelectOne" reference="../.."/>
        <labelFields>
          <string>unitOfMeasure</string>
      <string>uomType</string>
        </labelFields>
        <dynamicListTables/>
      </dataList>
    </SelectOne>
```

This is what I've tried, but it is just giving me a blank dropdown on the entry form instead of the desired result:

```
    <SelectOne id="tb26" label="Vertical Scale Uom" field="PlxRUnitOfMeasure1" isPartOfHierarchicalFlow="false" selectSingle="false" showAsCombo="false">
      <parent class="PanelGrid" reference="../.."/>
      <listenerEvents/>
      <validators/>
      <dataList class="DynamicList" table="PlxRUnitOfMeasure" valueField="" separator=" | " filterField="uomType,uomType" filterValue="DISTANCE,ALL">
        <selectList class="SelectOne" reference="../.."/>
        <labelFields>
          <string>unitOfMeasure</string>
      <string>uomType</string>
        </labelFields>
        <dynamicListTables/>
      </dataList>
    </SelectOne>
```